# Sencha: Prevent unmask after Sheet.hide

Tags: sencha-touch

I am performing a AJAX call after dismissing a Sheet. The problem is that when the slide transition finishes, Sencha unmasks the body, but AJAX request may still be running. How can I prevent the unmasking?

```
doSearch: function() {
    this.hide();

    // the controller handles this and tells the store to
    // load the data from an AJAX proxy
    this.fireEvent('search', ...);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing this unfortunately. It is deeply hooked into the layout system and trying to prevent it will result in a bunch of masking issues.

If you are using Sencha Touch 2, in your doSearch method, you could mask the the container immediately after hiding the sheet, so it looks like the mask has never disappeared.

```
this.getParent().setMasked(true);
```

And when the AJAX callback has finished:

```
this.getParent().setMasked(false);
```

You can also mask the viewport if you want to mask the entire screen:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked(true);
```

Comment: I found a workaround. You can specify a hide animation, which can be set to false to hide the sheet instantly. In this case, the sheet doesn't unmask the screen. I guess this could be called a bug, since it leaves the screen inaccessible, but in my case it's a feature. :)

There is one other caveat: the hide method's implementation ignores the animation, because it checks whether the sheet is hidden - which it is for some reason, even though it still visible - and if so, skips the animation. So, I had to hack around that, like so:

    sheet.hidden = false;
    sheet.hide(false);
    
Thanks.